# Table with rowspan breaks when hiding table row

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I am currently working on a web app and it uses `<table>` as their layout design.

Here is my sample code:

```js
function hideRow(link) {
  var row1 = document.getElementById("dataRow");
  var row2 = document.getElementById("toolbarRow");
  var row4 = document.getElementById("image");
  if (row1.style.display != "none" && row2.style.display != "none") {
    link.innerHTML = "Show";
    row1.style.display = "none";
    row2.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    link.innerHTML = "Hide";
    row1.style.display = "table-row";
    row2.style.display = "table-row";
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="width:1000px;height:300px">
  <table style="width:100%;height:100%">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=4 style="height:100%;width:20%;background-color:red;vertical-align:top">
        <table>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td style="border:1px solid black;max-height:30px;width:40%;">A</td>
      <td style="border:1px solid black;max-height:30px;width:40%;">B<button style="display:inline-block;float:right;" onclick="hideRow(this)">Hide</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="dataRow" style="display:table-row;">
      <td style="overflow:auto;width:40%;height:30%;position:relative;background-color:gray;">X</td>
      <td style="overflow:auto;width:40%;height:30%;position:relative;background-color:gray;">Y</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="toolbarRow" style="display:table-row;">
      <td colspan=2 style="height:30px;background-color:green;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="image" colSpan=2 style="border:1px solid blue;height:100%;width:80%;position:relative;vertical-align:top"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

So when the `Hide` button is clicked, `grey block` and `green block` are hidden with `display:none`.

In Google Chrome, it works as what I expected it to be, but in IE Edge the table shrinks, while `Block A` and `Block B` grows.

So my questions are:

1. Why the table behaves differently in both of the browsers?
2. Am I breaking the table because of the rowspan in the first row?

Comment: also most browsers have different default formats, i'd take a look at the W3 schools tutorials which tend to show this point quite well

Comment: I think that my question is more related to how browsers are drawing their table, but thanks for your reply =)

Comment: 1. Because IE is garbage. 2. No, you aren't breaking anything, you need a workaround for IE to make it behave the same. =]